# NestJS TypeORM Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') from DTO

Tags: typescript, nestjs, entity, typeorm, dto

I have this issue, `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` and when I remove this `userId` field, it works perfectly fine, so i know `userId` is causing the error. `userId` is from another entity. What am i missing? Thanks!

Here is my `report.entity.ts`

```
@Entity()
export class Report {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  //other fields here
  @Column()
  mileage: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.reports, { eager: true })
  user: User;
}
```

Here is my `report.dto.ts`

```
export class ReportDto {
  @Expose()
  id: number;

  //other fields here
  @Transform(({ obj }) => obj.user.id,)
  @Expose()
  userId: number;
}
```

Here is my `controller` code:

```
@Get()
getEstimate(@Query() query: GetEstimateDto) {
  return this.reportService.createEstimate(query);
}
```

Comment: in `obj.user.id` you're assuming that `obj.user` was fetched. The error saids `obj.user === undefined`

Answer (score 1):

I had some problem. But i added { eager: true } and then solved my problem

Comment: Hi, i think there are some typos here. Furthermore, you should format code as code in order to make it clear.